# char array assignment in a loop in C?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, char

So I know this has something to do with pointers and/or memory allocation, but I'm not quite sure how to fix it. For some reason, the following code prints nothing, when it should be printing the first character in a file (designated by a path "filename").

```
    int text[1000] = {};  

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( filename, "r" );
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
        int c = fgetc(fp);
        if ( c==EOF ) {
            break;
        } else {
            text[i] = c;  
        }
    }

    printf ( "%c", text[0] );
```

Thanks!

Comment: You never increment `i` so you only save characters in `text[0]`; as a result, you only write the last character, which is probably a newline, with the `printf()`.  You can only spot the newline by seeing a blank line in the output.  If (when) you increment `i`, you should also worry about reading too many characters into the array, and you should probably print the string instead of just one character.  Otherwise, you could read the first character into a variable and then simply read other characters and discard them.  And you should check that `fopen()` is successful before using `fp`.

Comment: change %c to %d and you will know the code (in ASCII) of the character you store in text[0] and why you didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not increment i so that what happens is you always update text[0] and at last it has only '\n' at text[0]. So it doesnt print anything.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char text[1000] = {};  

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r" );
    int i = 0;
    while(1) {
        char c = fgetc(fp);
        if ( c==EOF ) {
            break;
        } else {
            text[i++] = c;  
        }
    }

    printf ( "%c\n", text[0]);
}
```

This is the correct way to use.